# Android slider menu Item click not working

Tags: android

I am following the tutorial here http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/ to implement slider menu.

Using the code there I got warning ActionBarDrawerToggle is deprecated. So I replace

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```

to

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```

Also change the line

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        )
```

to

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,

            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    )
```

And

set drawer listener

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

And  onclick listener implemented like

```
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }
```

But it seems the the event is not called when I click the menu item, what could be the issue?

Comment: Did you call `setOnItemClickListener()` on the ListView?

Comment: Yes, actuality the project download from there seems working,  but the problem is when I integrate the code to my custom project. How can I debug where the mistake, thanks.

Comment: Commit your changes. Then copy and paste into your MainActivity the code from tutorial. Review changes by click in Revert (purple arrow on toolbar) then twice in name of your class. You would see the doubled view with your code before and after changes. That's the easiest way I think

Comment: Well, before all that, make sure your drawer View is listed last within the DrawerLayout. Otherwise, it'll be under some other View, and won't be clickable.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, I am defining some more component after list view, now I moved the list view as last element, the problem goes away. Thank you Mike , you saved my day...